# Installing Canon Pixma MG7760 in Ubuntu 16.04.02 lts

Tags: 16.04, drivers, printing

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.02 lts x 64 bit on a desktop PC. How can I now install a new Canon Pixma MG7760? All attempts so far have failed as I can't find appropriate driver and/or plug in that will actually work. My system recognizes the printer but a start page request results in the printer printing blank pages until I hit stop. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Canon supply drivers; if one starts here, http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/?personal  ...... just so you know where the trail starts ...

**but you want** http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100690202.html

and if you click to DOWNLOAD and SAVE what will be cnijfilter2-5.20-1-deb.tar.gz

if you can open a terminal; press 3 buttons control alt and t

and to paste, right-click at the prompt in the terminal and select PASTE

...... hit the ENTER key after each paste .. ok, so the commands to paste in are

```
cd Downloads

tar -xvxf cnijfilter2-5.20-1-deb.tar.gz

cd cnijfilter2-5.20-1-deb
```

so we are now ready to run the install script: Canon say to keep the printer turned off........ is it usb?

*If wireless, you need to have it talking to your router first

if you make the terminal full-page, so you can see it more clearly; now run the install script with the command

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

is all good now?

Canon also supply ScanGearMP to run the scanner; more details if you want them